# Add ordinal number column to output of custom verb in J

Tags: j

If I type `!i.10` it gives the factorial of first 10 numbers.
However if I try to add a column of ordinal numbers `>/.!i.10, 1+i.10`, then J freezes or I get an "Out of memory" error. How do I create custom tables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that what is happening is that you are creating something much bigger than you expect. Taking it in steps:

```
   1+ i. 10 NB. list of 1 to 10
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
   10 , 1+ i. 10 NB. 10 prepended
10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
   i. 10 , 1+ i. 10 NB. creates an 11 dimension array with shape 10 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 and largest value of 36287999
```

When you apply `!` to that `i. 10 , 1+ i. 10` you get some very large numbers. I am not sure what you are trying to do with the leading `>/.`

Is this what you had in mind?

```
   (!1 + i.10),. (1+i.10) NB. using parenthesis to isolate operations
       1  1
       2  2
       6  3
      24  4
     120  5
     720  6
    5040  7
   40320  8
  362880  9
3.6288e6 10
```

To give extended type and get rid of the `3.6288e6` we can use `x:`

```
 (x:!1 + i.10),. (1+i.10)
      1  1
      2  2
      6  3
     24  4
    120  5
    720  6
   5040  7
  40320  8
 362880  9
3628800 10
```

or tacit

```
   (x:@! ,. ]) @ (1+i.) 10
      1  1
      2  2
      6  3
     24  4
    120  5
    720  6
   5040  7
  40320  8
 362880  9
3628800 10
```

Or a version I find a little better

```
   ([: (,.~ !) 1x + i.) 10
      1  1
      2  2
      6  3
     24  4
    120  5
    720  6
   5040  7
  40320  8
 362880  9
3628800 10
```

Comment: Yes I wanted it like you did. Thanks.☺️

Comment: I am glad that it worked out for you. Remember that the language executes right to left for verbs and nouns. You might want to give the answer an upvote so that external viewers can see that the answer has been accepted.